# Changing In-Page Anchor Link Background Image When Active

Tags: javascript, css, anchor

I am using in-page link anchors to smooth scroll down my page. Everything works just fine and each link hovers to the appropriate image. However, I want the active section to have a different image to show the user where they are. I cant seem to get this to work with anything.

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="scrollnav">
<ul>
    <li class="scrolldot"><span><a href="#one">1</a></span></li>
    <li class="scrolldot"><span><a href="#two">2</a></span></li>
    <li class="scrolldot"><span><a href="#three">3</a></span></li>
    <li class="scrolldot"><span><a href="#four">4</a></span></li>
    <li class="scrolldot"><span><a href="#five">5</a></span></li>
    <li class="scrolldot"><span><a href="#six">6</a></span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS

```
#scrollnav { width: 75px; height: 150px; position: fixed; right: 0; top: 100px; z-index: 999999;}
#scrollnav ul li { height: 16px; width: 16px; padding: 0px 0px 7px 0px; }
span { text-indent: -99999px; }
.scrolldot a { display: block; height: 16px; width: 16px; background-image: url(../images/dots.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: -16px 0; }
.scrolldot a:hover { background-image: url(../images/dots.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0 0; }
.selected { background-color: red; }
```

This is an example of the section I would scroll to and would want active.

```
<section id="one">
<div id="mainimagewrapper">
    <div class="image1">
        <div class="image2">
            <div class="970content">
                <div id="textdiv">
                    <h1>This is headline.</h1>
                    <p>This would be a description if someone wanted to write stuff here. This would be a description if someone wanted to write stuff here. This would be a description if someone wanted to write stuff here.</p>
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Is it the links within #scrollnav that you want to do something when they are active? Also, in your example section above you have an ID of #mainimagewrapper and one of #textdiv. Are these same IDs used in each section? If so they shouldn't be as IDs should be unique.

Comment: scrollnav contains the links that I will want active and not active, yes. And the ID's above are only used in that section.

Answer (score 0):

/* ORDER to define anchor pseudo classes */

```
a, a:link, a:visited { ... css ...}
a:hover, a:visited:hover {... css ...}
a:active,a.my-active {... css ...}
a:focus {... css ...}
```

This way you define styling for browser default actions on an anchor.

After that, you might need to trigger some behaviors with javascript (in case the browser misbehaves due to #hash in hyperlink).

Using a jQuery action to add some of your flavour, like **.my-active** toggled onClick won't help you if you 'reload' the page. You will have to deduce the #hash from the hyperlink, then treat it for your styling.

Simply use jQuery [hashchange](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/hashchange) to get the #hash from hyperlink then trigger a class on your element in scope.

Otherwise, **if you just need a plugin to scroll-to** some place inside an opened page : http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/  or study [jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin).

Carry on

Comment: I've tried everything I can think of with CSS and nothing seems to work. The active pseudo class only seems to act on the actual click and not as an active section link. Make sense?

I think Jquery is the route, but I'm no where near skilled enough to write that on my own. :\

Basically, if my url is "myurl.com/index.html#one" I would want that  link active.

Comment: ... like .my-active toggled onClick **won't** help you if you 'reload' the page.

Comment: Its a one page site, so I wouldn't be reloading the page unless the user did it specifically. In that case it would just start the sequence over.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this, without writing your own jQuery script, is to check out Twitter Bootstrap's "Scrollspy" plugin. I believe it provides the effect you're looking for with very little configuration.

Link: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

Comment: This is exactly what I want to accomplish. Even how you scroll down their page and the left nav highlights based on the section they are on. I'm just a little confused on how to implement. Is there a separate bootstrap file I have to include in my head?

Comment: If you include this in your header:
`<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>`
It should work.